# Why is `before_save` not working in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try `u = User.new` followed by `u.save`, the `before_save` method is not being fired.

Here's my `User` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :encrypt_password

  def encrypt_password
    puts "Its getting called"
  end
end
```

https://railsforum.com/topic/1741-rails-4-and-before-save-method/

Comment: If you are just testing it is fired, you should use `Rails.logger.debug`. Normally this should just work.

Comment: @nathanvda: where is the log file to look at?

Comment: Is that a trick question? There should be a `log` folder in your rails folder, and it should contain a `development.log` file (if you are running in development mode).

Comment: @nathanvda: Rails.log.info "Hello" it does not print anything in development.log

Comment: You do mean `Rails.logger.info` right? I am using rails 4 with a before save without any problems. Is this your complete class you showed?

Answer (score 17):

The callback methods need to be either `protected` or `private`.

From here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html under the section `Types of callbacks`

Comment: puts "Hello" is still not printing anything to rails console. Any specific method to print in console.

Comment: It won't print to the console; it will appear on the shell you are running your server on.  Or if your server is running through something like apache or nginx it should be in their respective log file.

Comment: @Shane try logger.info or Rails::logger.info to debug